# Can I vectorize this Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm kind of new to Python and I have to implement "fast as possible" version of this code.

```
s="<%dH" % (int(width*height),)
z=struct.unpack(s, contents)

heights = np.zeros((height,width))
for r in range(0,height):
    for c in range(0,width):
        elevation=z[((width)*r)+c]
        if (elevation==65535 or elevation<0 or elevation>20000):
            elevation=0.0

        heights[r][c]=float(elevation)
```

I've read some of the python vectorization questions... but I don't think it applies to my case. Most of the questions are things like using `np.sum` instead of `for loops`. I guess I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to speed up this code...I think `heights[r][c]=float(elevation)` is where the bottleneck is. I need to find some Python timing commands to confirm this.
2. If it possible to speed up this code. What are my options? I have seen some people recommend `cython`, `pypy`, `weave`. I could do this faster in C but this code also need to generate plots so I'd like to stick with Python so I can use `matplotlib`.

Comment: [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) is an excellent Python profile viewer that shows time usage in a treemap format. Get the profile by turning `dostuff()` into `profile.runctx('dostuff()', globals(), locals(), filename='out.profile')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mention, the key to writing fast code with `numpy` involves vectorization, and pushing the work off to fast C-level routines instead of Python loops.  The usual approach seems to improve things by a factor of ten or so relative to your original code:

```
def faster(elevation, height, width):
    heights = np.array(elevation, dtype=float)
    heights = heights.reshape((height, width))
    heights[(heights < 0) | (heights > 20000)] = 0
    return heights

>>> h,w = 100, 101; z = list(range(h*w))
>>> %timeit orig(z,h,w)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.71 ms per loop
>>> %timeit faster(z,h,w)
1000 loops, best of 3: 641 µs per loop
>>> np.allclose(orig(z,h,w), faster(z,h,w))
True
```

That ratio seems to hold even for longer `z`:

```
>>> h,w = 1000, 10001; z = list(range(h*w))
>>> %timeit orig(z,h,w)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.44 s per loop
>>> %timeit faster(z,h,w)
1 loops, best of 3: 675 ms per loop
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  You also might want to mention reading the data in using `np.fromstring(contents, dtype=np.uint16)` (or `fromfile` if it's originally in a file) instead of `struct.unpack`.  It's usually significantly faster than unpacking into a tuple using `struct` and then converting to an array for large datasets.